# Documents not updating in MongoDB (using Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update objects in an array from my Mongo database and saving the updated values back to the database. However, after calling save on the data I changed, nothing gets updated to the database.

```js
router.post('/:poll*', (req, res)=>{
    var url = '/poll' + req.url;
    Poll.findOne({link: url}, (err, data)=>{
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        else{ 
            var theValue;
            for(var key in req.body){
                if(key === 'opt'){
                    theValue = req.body[key];
                }
            }
            var voteCount;
            if(data.voters[0] == null){
                data.voters[0] = {};
                data.voters[0][req.user.username] = theValue;
                data.options[0][theValue] = data.options[0][theValue] + 1;
            }
            else{
                if(data.voters[0][req.user.username] != theValue){
                    var previous = data.voters[0][req.user.username];
                    data.voters[0][req.user.username] = theValue;
                    data.options[0][theValue] = data.options[0][theValue] + 1;
                    if(previous){
                        data.options[0][previous] = data.options[0][previous] - 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(data.voters)
        data.save(function(err){
            if(!err){
                console.log('saved');
            }
            else{
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
        res.send("Your input has been submitted.");
    });
});
```

I also put console.log(data that I've changed) right before the (data that I've changed).save(function( ...)) code.

What can I do to fix this?

**EDIT (HOW I SOLVED THIS):**
It appears that Mongo does not save my array when I access the array and modify them like:

`data.voters[0][username] = value;`

Instead I resorted to popping out the object, modifying it, and then pushing it back in. Now I see the values being properly saved/updated in the database.

Aka something like:

`var obj = data.voters.pop();
obj[username] = value;
data.voters.push(obj);`

Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your program and debugging with `node --inspect-brk`?  Did you get any exceptions/errors?

Comment: @zero298 Hi, thank you for the suggestion -- I'm relatively new to node.js but tried out the --inspect-brk but nothing seemed to have came up. However, I seem to have "fixed" my issue by popping out the object from the array, changing its contents, then pushing it back into the object, and then saving.

Comment: Yes, you need to open the debugger.  Read the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/).  If you have Chrome installed, open Chrome and follow [this example](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27).

Comment: You need to put the `res.send()` inside the `data.save()` callback. MongoDB operations are asynchronous. You need to wait for the operation to be done before sending back a response.

Comment: Thank you for the link -- the second link you posted was actually the guide I followed earlier to debug but nothing seemed to have come up in the debugger was what I meant, but I'll take a look at the first link you posted and see if I missed something.